# exit recursion after first word match

Tags: c++, recursion

This function is designed to take a misspelled word and permute it, checking each complete permutation against a list of words until it finds a match.

Once a match is found, the function is meant to terminate and immediately return the matched word, without permuting further.

**In its current state, the function works, however it continues to permute and find matches until all permutations have been completed.**

The function find () may be considered a black box which returns true if the word matches a word in the dcnV vector, and false if it does not. This function is working correctly.

dcnV : A vector of strings containing a list of words from the dictionary.

pos : Integer used by the recursion algorithm.

p [] : Solution array.

used [] : Array which tracks which indexes have been used in the current 
permutation.

word : a word which has been passed into this function from the calling function (comes from a text file).

```
    string permute ( vector <string> dcnV , int pos , int p [] ,
    int used [] , string & word )
{
    string tgt = word;  //sets tgt to have the same size as word

    unsigned int n = word.size ();  //determines for loop range
    unsigned int i = 0;  //iterator

    /* base case: when the end of the array is reached,
     * map tgt to word using p array indexes
     * search dictionary vector dcnV for matching word
     * if found, return tgt
     */
    if ( pos == n && p [0] == 0 && p [n - 1] == n - 1 )
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            tgt [i] = word [p[i]];
        }

        if ( find ( dcnV , tgt ) )
        {
            cout << "\n  Found matching word: " << tgt;
            return tgt;
        }
    }

    // recursive permutation algorithm. this is functioning correctly
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( used [i] == 0 )
        {
            p [pos] = i;
            used [i] = 1;
            permute ( dcnV , pos + 1 , p , used , word );
            used [i] = 0;
        }
    }

    // if end of fn is reached without match, return tgt with '*' appended in
    // front
    return "*" + word;
}
```

Attempted solutions that don't work:

Using a static vector to hold matched words, then only returning the first element of this vector.

Setting a flag when a word is found, and adding a logic check at the beginning of the function that immediately returns if the flag is set.

setjmp, longjmp, exit, break, and exceptions may not be used.

Answer (score 0):

please use `-std=c++11` to compile, or just copy permute function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool find(vector<string> &vs, string &s) {
  // or use std::find, but you provide a wrong parameters
  for (int i = 0; i < vs.size(); i++) {
    if (vs[i] == s) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

string permute ( vector <string>& dcnV , int pos , int p [] ,
                 int used [] , string & word )
{
  string tgt = word;  //sets tgt to have the same size as word

  unsigned int n = word.size ();  //determines for loop range
  unsigned int i = 0;  //iterator

  /* base case: when the end of the array is reached,
   * map tgt to word using p array indexes
   * search dictionary vector dcnV for matching word
   * if found, return tgt
   */
  // if ( pos == n && p [0] == 0 && p [n - 1] == n - 1 )
  // {
  // when pos == n, we should terminate this recurve immediately
  if (n == pos) {
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
      tgt [i] = word [p[i]];
    }

    if ( find ( dcnV , tgt ) )
    {
      cout << "\n  Found matching word: " << tgt << endl;
      return tgt;
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

  // recursive permutation algorithm. this is functioning correctly
  for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
  {
    if ( used [i] == 0 )
    {
      p [pos] = i;
      used [i] = 1;
      string t = permute ( dcnV , pos + 1 , p , used , word );
      // we have found a solution, return now
      if (t != "") return t;
      used [i] = 0;
    }
  }

  // if end of fn is reached without match, return tgt with '*' appended in
  // front
  // suppose you do not search an empty string...
  return "";
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  vector<string> vs = {"abcd", "asdf", "qqwer", "werq"};
  string word = "reqw";
  string word_nonexist = "asdsaf";

  int p[100] = {0};
  int used[100] = {0};

  string t1 = permute(vs, 0, p, used, word);
  string t2 = permute(vs, 0, p, used, word_nonexist);
  // cout << t <<endl;

  return 0;
}
```